# How to edit the item name in Edit Control Block(ECB) using javascript in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I want to edit the item name (Edit Item) to custom name (any) in Edit control block (ECB) of `list` using JavaScript or jQuery in SharePoint.

[image: Please click for image ECB]

Answer (score 2):

You could change `Strings.STS.L_EditItem_Text`, its where the ECB gets its value for "Edit Item". It could be used in different places, so probably best to change it only when the CallOut on the ECB is used.

A possible solution could look like this, I dont have much experience with the OOTB ECB tbh, so there could be some better options out there.

```
$(".ms-list-itemLink").each(function(e,i)  { 

    $(this).click(function() {

        CalloutManager.forEach(function(i) {
            var stsValue = Strings.STS.L_EditItem_Text;
            if(i.isOpening()) { 

                i.addEventCallback("closing", function() { 
                    Strings.STS.L_EditItem_Text = stsValue;
                });

                i.addEventCallback("opening", function() { 
                    Strings.STS.L_EditItem_Text = "Something else";
                });

            }
        });

        Strings.STS.L_EditItem_Text = "Something else";
        $(this).unbind("click");
    });
});
```